# Flask-APScheduler with uwsgi works when testing but not when deployed via systemd service

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, systemd, apscheduler

I have a Flask app that I deploy using systemd, uwsgi, and nginx. I'd like the app to perform a set of daily tasks every morning. I chose Flask-APScheduler to accomplish this.

The daily tasks are successfully executed when I run the app directly from the command line with something like:

```
uwsgi --enable-threads --wsgi-file run.py --callable=app --socket=myapp.sock
```

However, when I deploy the app via a systemd service, the daily tasks are never executed.

**myapp.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp Service
After=syslog.target nginx.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/noslenkwah/myapp/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/noslenkwah/myapp/deploy.ini
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
TimeoutStopSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**deploy.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
pp = %D
module = run
callable = app

master = true
processes = 4
enable-threads = true
lazy-apps = true

socket = %Dmyapp.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

virtualenv = %Denv
```

I edited the files to hide any identifying info. Please excuse any subsequent typos. All original code executes without throwing errors.

Comment: Have you read this FAQ entry? https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-apscheduler-with-uwsgi

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Yes I have. I can get it to work with uwsgi when run from the command line. Something different happens when I start it as a systemd service that causes the problem.

Comment: Have you used tried enabling debug logging, as detailed in the troubleshooting documentation?